# Reconciling Different Definitions of Solvable Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

Looks like my class note defines solvable group differently from others:

> A finite group $G$ is called *solvable* if $H' \neq H$ for each subgroup $H$ of $G$ different from $\{1\}$,

where $H'$ is called the *commutator subgroup* of $G$ (correct me if I am wrong):
$$\begin{align}
H' :&= [H, H] \\
&= \langle [a, b] \mid a, b \in H \rangle \\
&= \langle a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \rangle.
\end{align}$$

And then on the same text there is problem like this:

> Show that a finite group $G$ is solvable if and only if these two are met: 
> $(\mathscr C_1): \{1\} = H_0 \lhd H_1 \lhd \ldots \lhd H_{i-1} \lhd H_i \lhd \ldots \lhd H_n = G$, where $H_i < G,$ and $i =\{1, 2, \ldots n\}$; 
>   $(\mathscr C_2):$ Factor group $H_i/H_{i-1}$ is abelian. 
>   (Note that these $\mathscr C$'s are actually Wikipedia's definition of solvable group [*here*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group).)

I think I am done proving that if $\mathscr C$'s are true $\Rightarrow G$ is solvable, but I am struggling with proving that if $G$ is solvable $\Rightarrow \mathscr C$'s. Any hints or help would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

**POST SCRIPT: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**

I have been working on this problem since first posted and, after getting some help from “Modded Bear” *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097884/what-is-set-builder-of-langle-h-k-rangle)*, I am able to put together the first part ofsolution like these:

> Lemma: Suppose that $G$ is solvable, then (i) each subgroup of $G$ is solvable, and (ii) each factor group of $G$ is solvable.

**(A) Proving that if $\mathscr C$'s are true then $G$ is solvable:** 
(1) Since $\mathscr C_2: H_i/H_{i-1}$ is abelian, therefore $\forall a, b \in H_i$, we have

$$\begin{align}
(H_{i-1})a(H_{i-1})b &= (H_{i-1})b(H_{i-1})a \tag{1}\\
(H_{i-1})ab &= (H_{i-1})ba \tag{2}\\
ab(ba)^{-1}(H_{i-1}) &= (H_{i-1}) \tag{3}\\
\underbrace{aba^{-1}b^{-1}}_{\in \   H'_{i}} &\in (H_{i-1}) \tag{4}\\
\therefore \forall x \in H'_{i} &\rightarrow x \in H_{i-1} \tag{5}\\
H'_{i} &< H_{i-1} \tag{6}\\
\because H_{i-1} < H_{i} &\rightarrow H'_{i-1} < H'_{i}\tag{7}\\
\therefore H'_{i-1} &\neq H_{i-1} \tag{8}
\end{align}$$
(2) With similar analysis, we can easily derive $H'_{i} \neq H_{i}$ for each subgroup of $G$, therefore per definition $G$ is solvable as desired. $\blacksquare$

**(B) Proving that if $G$ is solvable then $\mathscr C$'s are true:**

(1) ... 
(2) ...

Comment: Show that, if $G$ satisfies the conditions $C_1$ and $C_2$ then so does any subgroup of $G$. Then the $H \ne H'$ condition follows immediately.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Thanks! See the Post Script I just put in.

Answer (score 1):

For part (b), the goal is to show that if $G$ is a finite group with the property that $H' < H$ for every subgroup $H$, then there is a subnormal series
$$1 = H_0 \lhd H_1 \lhd \cdots \lhd H_n = G$$
where the factor groups $H_{i+1}/H_i$ are all abelian. (This is one definition of a solvable group.)

To get started, try setting $H_{n-1} = G'$. Then $G' < G$ (because of the given property) and $G' \lhd G$ (in fact, $G'$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$), so $H_{n-1} \lhd H_n$ and therefore $H_n / H_{n-1}$ is a group.

To show that $H_n / H_{n-1}$ is abelian, we need to show that any two elements $aH_{n-1}$ and $bH_{n-1}$ commute, where $a$ and $b$ are elements of $H_{n}$. So we require
$$aH_{n-1} bH_{n-1} = bH_{n-1} aH_{n-1}$$

This will be true if and only if
$$abH_{n-1} = baH_{n-1}$$
if and only if
$$a^{-1}b^{-1}abH_{n-1} = H_{n-1}$$
if and only if
$$a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \in H_{n-1}$$
and this is of course true because $H_{n-1}$ contains the commutators of all of the elements in $H_n$. We conclude that $H_n / H_{n-1}$ is abelian.

So that takes care of the first step in the subnormal series. If $H_{n-1}$ happens to be $1$, then we're done. Otherwise, you need to keep repeating this process: let $H_{n-2} = H_{n-1}'$. Once again, $H_{n-1}' < H_{n-1}$ (given property), and once again you want to show that $H_{n-1}/H_{n-2}$ is abelian. The exact same argument as above will work.

Eventually this process must terminate, because each subgroup is strictly smaller than the previous one, and $G$ is finite, so eventually one of the subgroups will have to be $1$.

Comment: Your logic seems interesting, but in the 3rd. paragraph you said that "To show that $H_n/H_{n−1}$ is abelian, we need to show that any two elements $aH_{n−1}$ and $bH_{n−1}$ commute..." and then you proceeded starting with the very property of commutativity to prove that $H_n/H_{n−1}$ is abelian. To me it seems like a circular argument. Did I misunderstand you here? Did I miss anything here? Let me know and thanks again for your time!

Comment: @A.Magnus: I changed the wording slightly. Note the chain of "if and only ifs" between $aH_{n-1}bH_{n-1} = bH_{n-1}aH_{n-1}$ and $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \in H_{n-1}$. If any of the the statements in the chain is true, then they are all true. Since the last statement is true by definition of the commutator subgroup, the first statement is also true: $H_n/H_{n-1}$ is abelian.

Comment: I think I learned a new proof technique from you today. Do you happen to have a link to a generalized statement of this technique? I would love to use it in other occasions. Thank you again for your time and labor!

Answer (score 0):

The idea for the other direction is to pick some natural $H_i$s guaranteeing the factor groups are abelian. $G'$ seems tempting for $H_{n-1}$. Do you see what to pick next, and how solvability guarantees you'll make it down to $e$ eventually?

Comment: Your logic makes sense, moving from the right to left along the series until it gets into the $e$. However, the lemma I quoted guarantees only that if $G$ is solvable, then each factor group of $G$ is *solvable*, not *abelian*. Did I misunderstand you here? Did I miss anything? Let me know and thanks for your time!

Comment: $G/G'$ is abelian

Comment: Thanks, let me take another look.