# What is set builder of $\langle H, K \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

I am looking left and right for a lemma to solve a problem on solvable group [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097110/reconciling-different-definitions-of-solvable-group), and I think I have found one under commutator group:

> For any two subgroups $H, K$ of $G$, the $[H, K]$ is a normal subgroup of $\langle H, K \rangle$.

To be sure I know the angle brackets "$\langle$" and "$\rangle$" stand for generator, and the commutator of $H$ and $K$ stands for:

$$\begin{align}
[H, K] :&= \langle [h, k] \mid h \in H, k \in K \rangle \\
&= \langle h^{-1}k^{-1}hk \rangle ,
\end{align}$$

but I don't know (or remember) and definition of $\langle H, K \rangle$. I would love to see the set builder of this $\langle H, K \rangle$, thank you for your time.

Comment: Did I answer what you where asking?

Comment: @ModdedBear : Thanks! See my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle H, K \rangle$ is the minimum subgroup of $G$ under inclusion containing both $H$ and $K$, it is also the intersection of all the the subgroups containing $H$ and $K$. basically it is $\langle H \cup K \rangle$

You can also look at it as the set of all finite products of the form $s_1s_2\dots s_n$ where $s_i\in H \cup K$. When talking about an arbitrary set $S$ we let $s_i$ or $s_i^{-1}\in S$, but since $H$ and $K$ are subgroups we can dispense of this restriction.

---

Proof that $H'=[H,H]$ is a normal subgroup of $H$:

it suffices to show that if we take an element $h'$ of $H'$ and an arbitrary element $x$ of $H$ then $xh'x^{-1}=h''$ for some $h''$ in $H$.

This is the same as saying that $xh'=h''x$ for some $h''$ in $H'$. Here is when the commutator comes in. Notice that $[a,b]ba=aba^{-1}b^{-1}ba=ab$ (This is why it is called the commutator)

Therefore $[x,h']h'x=xh'x^{-1}h'^{-1}h'x=xh'$. So the $h''$ we are looking for is $[x,h]h'$ which clearly does belong to $H'$

Comment: Sweet! I am reading your first paragraph with interest, you said that "it is also the *intersection* of all the subgroups containing $H$ *and* $K$." Shouldn't it therefore be $\langle H \cap K \rangle$ instead, since you are specifying both "intersection" and "and"?

Comment: Given a subset $S$ of $G$ we denote by $\langle S \rangle $ the smallest subgroup under inclusion which contains $S$. This is also the intersection of all the subgroups that contain $S$.

Comment: $\langle K,H \rangle$ is the smallest subgroup containing both $K$ and $H$. So it is the smallest containing $K\cup H$. This is because in general a set $X$ contains $K$ and $H$ if and only if it contains the union. Therefore we can think of $\langle K,H\rangle$ as $\langle K \cup H \rangle$. Notice that talking abouth $\langle K\cap H \rangle$ does not make too much sense, since the smallest subgroup containing $K\cap H$ is $K\cap H$ since the intersection of subgroups is a subgroup.

Comment: Thanks again. When you said that "$\langle S \rangle$ is the smallest subgroup *under inclusion* which ...," I just wanted to clarify (a) does that mean the angle brackets "$ \langle, \rangle$" here do not denote generator? (b) What does "under inclusion" mean exactly? Sorry, you got a slowpoke down here! :-)

Comment: $\langle S\rangle$ is read the subgroup generated by $S$. So yes, you could say those symbols mean generated. What I mean by minimum subgroup under inclusion is that if you take another subgroup containing $H$ and $K$ then it also contains $\langle H,K\rangle$

Comment: Can we say that $\langle H, H \rangle = \langle H \cup H \rangle = \langle H \rangle = H$? This is actually what I am going to use to solve the problem linked to his posting. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can say that. Although from the looks of that what you want to use is then that the commutator is a normal subgroup of a group. Which is much simpler than the full result you are using.

Comment: Many, many thanks! I have green-check marked and up-voted yours. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: thanks, just to be clear am I correct that want you want to use is that the commutator of a group is a normal subgroup?

Comment: Exactly, my text says "... Notes also that $H' := [H, H]$ is a normal subgroup of $H$... " Am wondering when can I be as knowledgeable as you... :-(

Comment: I added a proof that $H'$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you again!