# What does $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \notin H$ imply?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

​I am working on a problem on commutator subgroup of finite group. Long story short, I was given $H < G$ and $H' \neq H$ and am aiming to prove $H \lhd G$. As you know that $H'$ is commutator subgroup of $G$, in that

$$ \begin{align} H' &\neq H  \\
[H, H] &\neq H  \\
\langle [a, b] \mid a, b \in H \rangle &\neq H \\
\langle aba^{-1}b^{-1} \rangle &\neq H \\
aba^{-1}b^{-1} &\notin H . \\
\end{align}$$

And here is my question: What does this $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \notin H$ mean in this context, knowing that both $a$ and $b$ are elements of $H$ in the first place? What is its implication in term of solving this problem?

I guess my mind doesn't have yet the fluidity to dance around this info to connect the dots. Thanks for your time.

**POST SCRIPT (after responses from Pedro, Timbuc & Derek.) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~** 

After your responses, I gathered from Wikipedia [*here*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup), that,

> ... in other words, $G/H$ is abelian if and only if $H$ contains the commutator subgroup.

Therefore here are my analysis: 
(1) Since $H' \neq H \Longrightarrow H' \lneq H$, therefore $G/H$ is abelian. 
(2) That $G/H$ is abelian implies that,
$$
\begin{align}
Hg &= gH \\
g^{-1}Hg &= H \\
g^{-1}hg &\in H,
\end{align}$$
which further implies that $H \lhd G. \qquad \blacksquare$

Correct me if I am wrong again, and thanks again for your time.

Comment: You're thinking incorrectly. $H'$ is always a subgroup of $H$. That $H'\neq H$ means there are elements of $H$ that are not products of commtutators of elements of $H$. It usually better to avoid "thinking in symbols" since it leads to such "deductions" as in your post which are simply wrong.

Comment: It's not very clear, but $\;H'\neq H\;$ actually means (or **should** mean to you) that $\;H'\lneqq H\;$ , and this means there's an element in $\;H\;$ which is *not* a commutator element, and this last means: not an element generated by a finite number of basic commutators of elements of $\;H\;$

Comment: You should know that, if $H$ is a subgroup, and $a,b \in H$, then $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in H$, so you should have noticed yourself that you have made a mistake.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff : To Pedro, Timbuc & Derek : See the Post Script above, I am OK now? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Wikipedia statement means that $G/H$ is abelian if and only if $H$ contains $G'$ (not $H'$). In any case, the statement $"G/H$ is abelian" only makes sense if $H \unlhd G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt : I am wrong again! Do you have any suggestion on proof outline? Would love to hear it from you, thanks!

Comment: Proof of what? The fact that $H \ne H'$ alone does not imply that $H \unlhd G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Here is the real story: I posted the whole & complete problem 5 days ago here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097110/reconciling-different-definitions-of-solvable-group , but perhaps my posting was way too long and too complicated, nobody got interested. Therefor I decided to break the question into 2 parts, the second one is here. Perhaps some members would think  I am "playing cat and mouse" but hopefully there are some more who would appreciate my persistence & curiosity. (Note this is not a homework problem.) Thank you!

Comment: After reading your other post, I think you're trying to show that if $G$ is a finite group with the property that $H' < H$ for every subgroup $H$, then there is a subnormal series
$$1 = H_0 \lhd H_1 \lhd \cdots \lhd H_n = G$$
where the factor groups $H_{i+1}/H_i$ are all abelian. (This is one definition of a solvable group.) I will add an answer under the other post, where it will be in the correct context.