# Proof Using iff Intermediate Lines

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I am posting this question motivated by *Bungo*'s response to my question [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097110/reconciling-different-definitions-of-solvable-group) -- scroll down to his/her response and comment. It was the first time I've seen this technique.

It looks like a circular argument but seems logical to me. *Bungo* wrote that if you have two statements, say $S_1$ and $S_2$, if you can provide lines of argument from $S_1$ leading to $S_2$ and if all these lines are on if-and-only-if basis, then if $S_2$ is true then $S_1$ will also be true.

I would love to use this technique in other settings, let me if you happen to know a link to a generalized statement of this technique. Does it have a name? Or is it just little common-sense trick that should be obvious to everybody?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That follows directly from the properties of if-and-only-if: If you have $P \Leftrightarrow Q$, then either $P$ and $Q$ are both true statements, or both false (that is the definition of if-and-only-if). Furthermore, $\Leftrightarrow$ is a equivalence relation, especially transitive: if $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ and $Q \Leftrightarrow R$ then we also have $P \Leftrightarrow R$. You can lift this to more than one intermediate statements. So even if there are intermediate steps between $S_1$ and $S_2$ in your proof, you still have $S_1 \Leftrightarrow S_2$ if all those intermediate steps are if-and-only-ifs.

Comment: Thanks, have checked and up-voted your response.