# different definitions of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

A group is classically defined as a set with a binary operation (the group product) which is associative, such that there is a unit and for every element there is an inverse.

I know we can define a group in many different ways: for example as a heap, that is a set with a ternary operation $[x,y,z]$ satisfying certain properties.

Do you know other (equivalent) definitions of group? Also any reference to textbooks/papers/other accounting this problem will be accepted as an answer.

Comment: Here is an alternative definition : http://planetmath.org/alternativedefinitionofgroup

But it is not that different from the usual definition.

Comment: Basically there is only one definition of a group. More interesting are different definitions of, say, solvable groups - see [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097110/reconciling-different-definitions-of-solvable-group).

Comment: Would something like "a group is a monoid with both a left and a right inverse" interest you? Or "a finite group is a finite cancellative semigroup". (Neither are awfully difficult to prove.)